# What is the term for shapes that contain any line between two points within the shape?

Tags: geometry

Is there a term for the set that consists of all shapes of which every line stretched between two points in the shape is entirely contained in the shape? E.g., circles, rectangles and  triangles are in this set, but a bagel-shape (a circle with a "hole" in the middle) isn't because you can have a line which starts and ends in the shape, but that isn't entirely contained in the shape:[image]

Comment: Cf. [simply connected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simply_connected_space)

Comment: A convex shape? https://undergroundmathematics.org/glossary/convex-shape

Comment: Isn't this the notion of being "simply connected"?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_set

Comment: how would you classify [pentagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentagram) or [מגן דוד](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexagram)?

Comment: Simply connected is if there's a _path_ between every two points. I'm looking for the same but with (straight) lines.

Comment: @Jamminermit bingo! A convex shape!

Comment: @J.W.Tanner I would classify those as _not_ included in the set

Comment: in that case, I do think *convex* is what you want